# searching contacts in android by voice recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am working on **sms application** in android in which user have to input contact by saying the name of recipient. i want this by **voice recognition** in android but i dont know how to search contacts by voice i e when user speaks a contact name voice search give me the ***phone number*** of this particular contact.
is there any way of doing this by using

> `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app uses RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH and the user says "Call Andrew" and "Andrew" is within the contact list, the app will start a phone call to Andrew by looking up that person in the contact list.

Is that your goal?

If you want your app to get the list of possible contacts and process it, then that is going to take more steps. Namely:

1. get list of Contacts using the Android API
2. send and Intent with RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH
3. compare speech recognition results from the Intent with the people in the contacts,
   perhaps using a phonetic matching algorithm like [Soundex](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html)

Comment: till now i am just comparing  the result with contacts name can you suggest me how to increase the probability of matching contacts because it is recognizing 'james' and 'games ' same

Comment: In that case, I think you need to ask to user to disambiguate. Or, you could give the user a chance to cancel before proceeding.


I think Android speech recognizer has its own preferences about which words are more likely than others. Thus, it is possible that even though the user says "james" it will always return "games" first, if it thinks that "games" is more likely.